# Is there support for OAUTH2's 'Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant' authentication flow in Symfony2 bundle?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, oauth-2.0

I have written an API which supports OAUTH2's 'Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant' authentication workflow. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.3

I have a Symfony2 application and would like users to be able to input their username and password into a form and for the security system to exchange these with my API for an access_token.

I know its possible to write a custom authentication handler to accomplish this task but if possible I'd like to use an off the shelf tool. After some research I can see lots of libraries support only the more traditional 3 legged worktflow.

Are there any libraries that integrate the 'Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant' workflow into the Symfony security system?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) does. Grant type: client_credentials

There is some documentation on it [here](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/04/securing-syfmony2-rest-service-wiith.html), not specific to 'Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant' but you should be able to work it out. If you do, please create a PR on GitHub with some extra documentation for the bundle.